# Android Material Design TextInputLayout - How do i focus and call onClick listener, but no keyboard should appear

Tags: android, material-design

I am currently trying to use the Android Material Design TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText to create a DatePicker, where the user cannot enter any input themself but only use the DatePicker. This currently works fine and can be seen on the image, however i would love the user to get a visual feedback when they click on the edit text. I cannot make this happend without the keyboard appering when the user clicks on the field...

I have currently tried to set the xml values for focusableInTouchMode to true and then setting focus with view.requestFocus(); but this doesnt work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting API >=21 you can set the following attribute to your editText and achieve what you want:

```
yourEditText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

For previous APIs you can get rid of the soft input immediately after focus by calling the following:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

UPDATE:

try consuming the touch event with a touchlistener:

```
yourEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
    }
});
```

by returning true, you have the listener consume the event and the keyboard shouldn't pop up.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I have now tried this, but with no luck... The keyboard still appears on screen. I am using API >= 21 @Nikos Hidalgo

Comment: @Emil check another implementation on my updated answer